# Formula if "C" is empty

Tags: excel, excel-formula

For now I have this formula:

```
d = abs(b-c) * a
```

Here is the example:

```
=abs(0,8894-0,8291)*10000
```

The result is `603`.

Now, I'm trying to find `c`, Here is what I do so far:

```
c = abs(b*a)/d
```

How can I achieve it?

Comment: Do you just need the combination of both formulas?

Comment: hi @snenson yes i do

Comment: But you need d to calculate c and you need c to calculate d its like an differnential equation where you need the value itself to calculate it.

Comment: `=IF(c<b,b-d/a,b+d/a)`.

Comment: Since you have abs, c can have two values. This should do: c = ((d/a)-b)*-1 or c = ((d/a)+b)

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for, is the "[solver](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/define-and-solve-a-problem-by-using-solver-5d1a388f-079d-43ac-a7eb-f63e45925040)" feature of Excel. Be aware this is a numerical method, which works with approximation, and therefore can have accuracy issues.